# add file to git repo and its rejected

Tags: git, github

Trying to add a file to my repo and when it comes back as rejected

```
! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push
some refs to 'SITE' hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of
your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the
remote chsanges (e.g. 'git pull') hint: before pushing again.
```

I have tried a git pull and it hasn't updated my local files. Could someone assist?

Comment: Do you have master checked out locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git fetch` if `git pull` does not work and then `git rebase` then you should be able to push your changes to the remote repo.